# How to convert a defaultdict to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a defaultDict to a pandas dataframe, but I'm unable to do so.

If I print the defaultDict using the following piece of code:

```py
for uid, user_ratings in top_n.items():
    print(uid, [iid for (iid, _) in user_ratings])
```

I get the following results:

```
196 ['408', '64', '318', '511', '963', '169', '187', '98', '174', '427']
186 ['318', '1449', '511', '313', '498', '357', '64', '190', '191', '114']
22 ['12', '56', '64', '205', '302', '641', '98', '603', '527', '408']
244 ['483', '14', '178', '603', '479', '134', '12', '513', '98', '48']
# and the list goes on
```

What I have tried : (I know it doesn't make any sense at all)

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[userId] + ratings[0] for userId, ratings in top_n.items()], 
                   columns=['id', 'user_id', 'Ratings'])
```

Output:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list

What I would like to have:

```
id | user_id | Ratings
----------------------
1  | 196     | ['408', '64', '318', '511', '963', '169', '187', '98', '174', '427']
2  | 186     | ['318', '1449', '511', '313', '498', '357', '64', '190', '191', '114']
(upto so on)
```

Comment: If you run `[[userId] + ratings[0] for userId, ratings in top_n.items()]` does it give you the same error? What is the value of `type(ratings[0])`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert defaultdict to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62813878/how-to-convert-defaultdict-to-pandas-dataframe)